# Turn on/off ESP8266 by a transistor

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator, esp8266, switching

I would like to turn off and on a circuit by another circuit. I believe that could be easily achieved by a transistor but when there is a voltage regulator and an ESP8266 with wide range of input current I'm lost.

I have the ESP8266 programmed to send a notification when it's turned on. The V1 supply has unfortunately too low current to power the ESP so I have to power it by the V2 (4xAA 1.5V batteries should be probably enough to feed the voltage regulator 3.3V + 1.1V it's dropout and some transistor dropout)

The circuit below is my amateurish attempt that can be probably all wrong.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7LHRP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: My advice is using a voltage regulator with a shutdown input. There are **plenty** of those available. Simpler, cheaper, known to work.

Comment: You are going to have a hard time turning on that transistor using high-side switching.  The reason for this is that it will be difficult to get the gate voltage high enough above the source voltage.

Comment: A high side switch typically needs to be a P-FET or a PNP.  To use an "N" device you need a voltage booster.  Something like a Richtek USB power switch chip has that built in, though there are better alternatives.  Since you need a regulator anyway, picking one with a shutdown input and low current in shutdown mode would be a lot simpler.

Comment: Follow Janka's advice.

Comment: Would you like to turn your ESP "on or off" remotely ? Because what you are describing sounds kind of like a "sensor" when someone opens a switch, in practical use for example when somebody opens a door. Then it would be much easier to define one pin as an input pin, so that when the loop ( switch ) is closed, you get a positive or negative input, and therefore the notification.

Comment: As you say, it's kind of sensor that when somebody opens it, pretty rarely in my case, I would like to receive a notification. As it would be opened for a few seconds maybe once a month. It would be a waste to have it turned on all the time.

Comment: Thanks Janka for advice and also for other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in one of the comments, there is a simpler and more efficient way to do this using a DC-DC converter rather than a linear regulator.  Here's one way to do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffXLeD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This uses a [Microchip MIC23050](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mic23050.pdf) high-efficiency buck regulator so you can power it directly from your 4 AA battery supply.  The EN input can be driven directly from a logic output.  The choice of the diode D1 is not critical -- we just need a small (~0.5V) voltage drop from the nominal +6V of the supply.

Not only is this simpler and has fewer parts, but it's also pretty inexpensive - around US $1 for everything.

Comment: Beware that using a DC-DC converter in a *radio* circuit may require taking extra care to ensure that it does not introduce a source of interference or distort the output signal.  It definitely can be done, and it is more efficient in most cases, but it requires more care than a linear regulator would.  Naturally both are available with enables.

Comment: Good point.  Also, circuit layout is typically more critical with this kind of supply vs. a linear regulator, but it's much more efficient which may be useful for a battery-powered application.

Comment: Thank you for the provided link but unfortunately I can't get one around or find it on ebay. I have found LM2576T-3.3 that seems to be a good alternative!?

Comment: The LM2576 is a good part, if a little more expensive and a little less efficient, but very solid part and available from multiple vendors.  My recollection is that it needs a relatively higher input voltage (5.4V?) so you will want to make sure that it meets your needs.